Distinguishing between page reloads and redirects for video autoplay in React
Problem:
I'm working on a React application where I have implemented video autoplay functionality using the react-player library. The videos autoplay correctly when the page redirects (e.g., from localhost:5173/ to localhost:5173/home), as there is user interaction involved. However, I'm facing issues when the page reloads (e.g., from localhost:5173/home to localhost:5173/home).
Videos autoplay on page redirects but not on page reloads.
I prefer not to mute the video for autoplay to work due to user experience considerations.
Question:
How can I reliably distinguish between a page reload and a page redirect in my React application?
Is there a way to handle video autoplay on page reloads without muting the video?
Code:
const VideoPlayer = ({ url, cb, videopause, setVideoPause, index }) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const handlePlay = () => {
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (![-1].includes(index)) {
      setIsPlaying(true);
      setVideoPause(false);
    }
  }, [index, setVideoPause]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`${videopause
          ? "h-[15vh] md:h-[25vh]"
          : "h-[50vh] md:h-[60vh] md:min-w-fit"
          } rounded-lg relative flex`}
      >
        <ReactPlayer
          className="react-player"
          url={url}
          playsinline={true}
          autoPlay={true}
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          controls={false}
          playing={isPlaying && !videopause}
          onEnded={cb}
        />
        {!isPlaying && (
          <button
            onClick={handlePlay}
            className="absolute w-20 h-20 text-white bg-black bg-opacity-50 rounded-full"
            style={{
              top: "50%",
              left: "50%",
              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
            }}
          >
            Play
          </button>
        )}
        {videopause && (
          <>
            <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-black opacity-30 rounded-3xl"></div>
            <img
              src={replay_icon}
              alt="Replay"
              className="absolute w-8"
              style={{
                top: "50%",
                left: "50%",
                transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                setVideoPause(false);
                setIsPlaying(true);
              }}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;

I tried using flags to track video playback status, but they show the video as playing even when paused. Also, i have tried this :
const navigationType = performance.navigation.type;
    if (navigationType === 1) {
      console.log("Page is being reloaded");
      // Reset playback state as needed on reload
      setIsPlaying(false); // Example: reset to false on reload
      localStorage.removeItem("videoPlaybackState"); // Clear stored state on reload
    }
  }, []);

but it works even when the page is redirected. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I would suggest you use performance.navigation API with more specific handling for both cases.
Since performance.navigate.type returns  a value that represents how the page was navigated, you can leverage on it to differentiate between reloads and other navigations e.g
0 for TYPE_NAVIGATE
1 for TYPE_RELOAD
2 for TYPE_BACK_FORWARD
255 for TYPE_RESERVED
check MDN Web Docs: Performance API 
And also use local storage to persist a flag or a state indicating whether the page has been reloaded

Thank you for your comment. It worked. I used (if (navigationType === performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) to detect the reload and set my isPlaying state to false to add a button on the page reload. Since performance.navigation.type is deprecated, I looked at the docs and found the replacement for this, the PerformanceNavigationTiming: type property, but for some reason, it wasn't working 100%. Once any page is reloaded, even if you go back and redirect, it still consoles "page reloaded," so for now, I'm using performance.navigation.type.

The docs for React Player mention setting playing to true to play the video. You can set the state to default true on page reloads.
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);

<ReactPlayer 
  playing={isPlaying && !videopause}
  onPlay={() => setIsPlaying(true)}
  onPause={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
/>


I have tried this before, but it doesn't work. When I'm redirecting the page from '/' to '/home', the video works, and here are the console.log statements: ('videopause' -> false) and ('isPlaying' -> true). However, on reload, the video doesn't start, and the console.log statements are the same. I think this issue is related to the browser autoplay policy. Additionally, if I pass the muted prop to the ReactPlayer, the video works even on reload.
